# Align center list items using background image as bullets

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've been trying to fix this for an hour now and can't find a solution.

What I want is a centered list with background image as "ticks".

I want this:

[image]

Works as it should except the dots are aligned to the left of the list `ul` (1140px wide) and not the left of the list item `li` which is centered.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: ul { text-align: center }
li { background:url("dots.png") no-repeat 0 0; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the *dots* to be aligned to the left of `ul`, Use *dot* image as background:

```css
ul li {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(path/to/dot.png) 0 center no-repeat;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo #1](http://jsbin.com/usaKaSA/1/edit)**

### Update

If you need the *dots* to be aligned to the left of list items, use the following:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: url(path/to/dot.png) 0 center no-repeat;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo #2](http://jsbin.com/usaKaSA/2/edit)**

Comment: interesting use of `white-space: pre-line;`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the css `:before` pseudo-class:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

li:before {
  content: "\2022";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6y9d/

Comment: Works but I would like to use the background-image not content: "\2022". The disc that content: "\2022" is giving me it's a bit chunky. Thanks!

Comment: Also, in the future I might want to use a different background image, a tick, a heart, etc ... so a background-image is necessary.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion with the "dots".