# Unordered list items in one line with bullets

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am building a responsive page that has an unordered list. My requirements are that the `li` items display in one line with bullets in bigger screen resolution:

[image]

And break down to one bullet point per line when shrunk down:

[image]

So far, I have been to get all three lines in one without bullets and 3 lines without bullets. When I get bullets for smaller screen size I do not get in one line for bigger screen. I am not sure where I am going wrong. I am guessing I am missing something in `list-style-type` setting.

HTML

```
<div>

<ul class="list">
    <li>Text of line 1 Text of line 1 Text of line 1 Text of line 1 Text of line 1 </li>
    <li>Text of line 2 Text of line 2 Text of line 1 Text of line 2 Text of line 2  </li>
    <li>Text of line 3 Text of line 3 Text of line 1 Text of line 3 Text of line 3 </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

CSS

```css
.list li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .list{
     display: block;
     list-style: circle;
  }
}
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ug5k3k15/

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `li items display in one line with bullets in bigger screen resolution`? It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: In your media query your selector is `.list` instead of `.list li`. Change it and it works just fine.

Comment: @Blunderfest Besides, `display: block;` should be `display: list-item;` otherwise `list-style` won't affect the elements.

Comment: When the screen size in 600+px, I want it like this http://i.imgur.com/z7d58lX.jpg.and the screen size is < 600px, I wasnt it like this http://i.imgur.com/W02Miua.jpg. I amusing media queries but havent been able to get the list correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that you should use `.list li` selector in the `@media` rule to target the list items.

Besides - as I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557509/unordered-list-items-in-one-line-with-bullets/25557963#comment39910086_25557509) - since you are changing the type of display of the `li` elements to `inline` or `block`, `list-item` will no linger affect the element:

> **[12.5.1 Lists: the 'list-style-type', 'list-style',... properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type)**
>
> `list-style` Applies to: elements with `display: list-item`

One option is to use CSS float instead, as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ug5k3k15/4/)** (Check the demo for more details including the clearfix)

```css
.list li {
    float: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .list li {
        float: none;
        list-style-position: outside;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3861559 Don't mention it. In addition I suggest using a custom `background-image` instead of the default markers like `disc`, `circle`. If you are interested in this method, take a look at [my](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186018/how-to-put-a-bullet-beside-the-heading-elements-as-background-image/22186050#22186050) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452697/list-items-with-bullets-on-top/18452737#18452737) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450920/align-center-list-items-using-background-image-as-bullets/18451007#18451007)

Comment: A follow up question. At 600+px, i want it center aligned. But since its floatign left, I am not able to do it. Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: @user3861559 Well, in that case you should set a proper width to the `<ul>` (equal to summation of widths of `<li>`s) and also add `margin: 0 auto` to achieve the result.

Comment: @user3861559 Here is **[the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ug5k3k15/8/)** There are sets of CSS declarations, if you have any question I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @user3861559 One other option is displaying the `<ul>` as `inline-block` and use `text-align: center` on the wrapper div to make it center without specifying any width! http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ug5k3k15/13/

Answer (score 1):

Because your CSS is wrong. Change it to this:

```
.list li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .list li {
        color:#000;
        list-style-type: disc;
        display:list-item;
    }
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mabqLL5n/)

All sizes:

```
.list li {
            color:#000;
            list-style-type: disc;
            display:list-item;
        }
```

Basically, your display block has to be changed and you needed to apply the list-style to the `li element`. For all sizes, just get rid of the media-query

Comment: That worked for screen size < 600. While its > 600px, it still doesn't display the bullets.

Comment: I understood you wanted that only under 600px. I'm editing the code for all sizes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it really responsive, you can have it switch to vertical list exactly when the content can no longer fit horizontally (i.e., either line 1,2,3 all on one line, or on different lines). Basically you just compute inner and outer width, and change the class of the ul depending on whether which value is larger. Anyways, here's the fiddle and code.

http://jsfiddle.net/ug5k3k15/10/

```
function main() {
    var outerWidth = $('ul').width();
    console.log('Outer width is ' + outerWidth);
    var innerWidth = 0;
    $('ul').find('span').each(function(index,value){
        //Stick span in li since li width fills available width (i.e. not actual width)
        //Manually add margin/padding values
        var current = $(value).outerWidth() + 15 + 10;
        innerWidth += current;
        console.log('li['+ index+']\'s width is '+current);
    });
    console.log('Inner width is ' + innerWidth);
    if(innerWidth > outerWidth){
        $('ul').attr('class','verticalList');
        console.log('Content cannot fit in single row!');
    } else {
        console.log('Content fits!');
        $('ul').attr('class','list');
    }
}
```

PS: The hackyScrollbarResizeListener() function is used so that a window resize event is called if a scrollbar is created/destroyed; this is helpful for calculating widths because sometimes scrollbars pop in and out of existence without you noticing and it messes things up.